# Using the Navigation stack on a larger vehicle

Tags: ros, navigation, lidar, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,
I have a mobile robot(Rectangle size) of about 10X16 ft. I am trying to make it autonomous in an indoor area. The scene is not gonna be much cluttered. Imagine it is in pose A and I need it go to pose B.

I can get encoder data from the Omnidirectional wheels on the base and the laser scan data from the LIDAR. Could you please advise whether its advisable to move ahead with this package for this problem?. Also have anyone out there tried using ros navigation on a larger vehicle?. Please let me know, Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198993/using-the-navigation-stack-on-a-larger-vehicle/) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe as long as you set the 'holonomic robot' parameter to true, specify the footprint (size of your robot) of your vehicle properly, set the voxel grid parameter to true (assuming your robot is probably pretty high and you dont want to hit something from the ceiling) instead of just a 2D costmap so your 3D LIDAR data is actually used for height information as well, i believe you should not have a problem using the nav stack. You just have to make sure your velocity and acceleration values are correct/reasonable for the robot of your size.

Have a look at http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d as well as http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-01-04**:
Hi, ı want to communicate my lidar with mobile robot. this vehicle has dc motor with encoder. But ı don't know how to do it. I am new on ROS. could you help me this situation Mr. @l0g1x